# Perl: Experimental Features and Perldoc

Tags: perl, perldoc

I was inadvertently using Perl 5.14's experimental [autoderef](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.22.0/pod/perl5140delta.pod#Array_and_hash_container_functions_accept_references) feature in Perl 5.20 and of course getting warnings about its use. The `diagnostics` pragma explains how to suppress these warning messages if need be; however, I wanted to learn more about the root cause of this warning (and really the feature overall), so I turned to `perldoc` to learn more about `autoderef`.

The `perldoc experimental` command lists the `autoderef` feature with a high-level statement about its purpose, but nothing more.

The `perldoc perlexperiment` command provides greater detail about other experimental features, but `autoderef` is not mentioned at all.

I've tried various other `perldoc` options (e.g., `-v`,`-f`,etc), but to no avail.

What is an effective way to traceback such `warning` / `diagnostics` messages using `perldoc`?  Are experimental features not covered in `perldoc`?

**UPDATE**: Please see @ThisSuitIsBlackNot's EXCELLENT answer below.

For further clarity and reference: it seems odd that the `autoderef` namespace did not hold throughout all the various documentation (i.e., `perlexperiment`, `perldelta`, `perldoc` etc.). `perldoc experiment` called it `autoderef`, `perldelta5140` referred to it as `auto-deref`. `perldoc perlexperiment` used some language from the `perldelta` page, but not `autoderef` or the like.

**Since `diagnostics` stated the associated warnings could be suppressed using `no warnings "experimental::autoderef"`. It would be nice to use that as a starting point in `perldoc`. That is, find relative documentation with `perldoc experimental::autoderef`, matching the syntax and semantics provided by `diagnostics` and/or `warnings`.**

Comment: After a few problems in the past, it was decided that new features would go through a period flagged as experimental to be able to change or remove them if problems are found

Comment: @ikegami this part makes perfect sense.  The answer below provides a lot of great detail about `autoderef`.  The second, more general piece of my question was regarding the difficulty in finding details about the experimental feature(s).  I've updated the question to more explicitly state that concern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When features are added to or removed from the Perl core, they are documented in `perldelta`, so if you get a warning about a feature being experimental, that's a good place to look.

If you know the feature was added in Perl 5.14.0:

```
perldoc perl5140delta
```

If not:

```
grep -lr autoderef $(dirname $(perldoc -l perldelta))
```

The description you linked to in `perl5140delta` is pretty thorough on its own, but notice that it gives a list of built-in functions that autoderef applies to. Run `perldoc -f <function>` to see the documentation for  built-in functions, e.g. [`perldoc -f push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html):

> Starting with Perl 5.14, `push` can take a scalar `EXPR`, which must hold a reference to an unblessed array. The argument will be dereferenced automatically. This aspect of `push` is considered highly experimental. The exact behaviour may change in a future version of Perl.

The reason for the warning is documented in [`perl5200delta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html):

> The "auto-deref" feature is experimental.
>
> Starting in v5.14.0, it was possible to use push, pop, keys, and other built-in functions not only on aggregate types, but on references to them. The feature was not deployed to its original intended specification, and now may become redundant to postfix dereferencing. It has always been categorized as an experimental feature, and in v5.20.0 is carries a warning as such.

And actually, autoderef *is* mentioned in `perlexperiment`, although it's under the heading "Array and hash container functions accept references" (the same heading used in `perl5140delta`):

> - **Array and hash container functions accept references**
>
>   Introduced in Perl 5.14.0
>
>   The ticket for this feature is [perl #119437].

If you view the [online documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlexperiment.pod), you can follow the link to [issue #119437](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=119437) in Perl's issue tracker, where you can follow development details related to the feature.

---

In case you were curious, it looks like [autoderef is getting axed](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/262309092c2de925e7ae4a527174f8dc2a0ec7b7) in the next release:

> **The `autoderef` feature has been removed**
>
> The experimental `autoderef` feature (which allowed calling `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`, `splice`, `keys`, `values`, and `each` on a scalar argument) has been deemed unsuccessful. It has now been removed; trying to use the feature (or to disable the `experimental::autoderef` warning it previously triggered) now yields an exception.

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT answer. It took some digging for me to find the `perl5140delta page` discussing `autoderef`.  I'll add the following piece to the question for historical reference, but I'm surprised the `autoderef` namespace did not hold throughout all the various documentation (i.e., `perlexperiment`, `perldelta`, `perldoc` etc.). Took more effort to find that I had hoped.  Since `diagnostics` stated the warnings can be supressed using `no warnings "experimental::autoderef"` I'd really hope one could find relative documentation with `perldoc experimental::autoderef`

Comment: perldoc is a *great* tool, but sometimes using it can be kind of like going on a treasure hunt. The fact that it was spelled `autoderef` in some places and `auto-deref` in others didn't help. I really wish perldoc had a full-text search capability, but I usually just resort to Googling "perldoc foo". I'm not sure if the documentation for other experimental features is as hard to track down, but if it is, it might be worth making a suggestion on the [Perl5 porters mailing list](http://lists.perl.org/list/perl5-porters.html).

Comment: That's a great suggestion.  Maybe I will do that.  I often only have access to the local `perldoc` so trying to dig up documentation outside of it isn't always available.    Thanks again for the very good, thoughtful response.